# From Tai O to downtown Hong Kong by ferry

Tags: public-transport, hong-kong, ferries

I plan to go to see the big Buddha by cable car and then take a bus/taxi to Tai O village. Is there an option to take a ferry back to the center of Hong Kong? If so, where can I find a schedule? Do I need to purchase tickets in advance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tung Chung / Tuen Mun ferry mentioned in another answer only runs a few times a day, and doesn't bring you back to HK island...

The best way to go back to HK island by ferry is to take a bus from Tai O to Mui Wo, and then [the ferry to Central](http://www.nwff.com.hk/route/get_route.php?id=df056ac0-ac9e-4813-ba89-928c441dfec6&route_id=7&submenu_num=3).

Comment: Thanks. May I ask which bus goes from Tai O to Mui Wo and how often?

Comment: Can't remember the number offhand, but it's not like there's a million buses there. There's only a couple of lines. Ask/check the signs.

Comment: It's bus number 1. Also, from the Big Buddha to Tai O is bus number 21.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [ferry from Tai O that will take you back to Tung Chung or on to Tuen Mun](http://www.fortuneferry.com.hk/timetable.php). You can get on the MTR at the station in Tung Chung, from Tuen Mun I think there is a bus to the Tsuen Wan MTR station.

The ferry doesn't travel very often on weekdays; I think there's only one boat then and the trip from Tai O to Tuen Mun and back is almost an hour each way, so there is 2 hours between departures from Tai O. You pay when you get on the ferry. The public transit alternative is the bus from Tai O to Tung Chung, which leaves more frequently.